# How to get working Grails 2.2.4 with Oracle 12c?

Tags: grails, oracle12c, oracle-xe

Debian 8.2
Java 7 + jre
Grails 2.2.4
Oracle 12c
Tomcat 7

Having troubles to startup grails after instalation Oracle 12c.
Everything working fine on Debian 8.2 + Oracle 10XE.
THX for help

app.log:

```
        2016-01-01 20:57:43,245 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing /bundle-bundle_applications_head.css, /styles/dist/gui/core/main.css, /styles/dist/gui/core/top-panel.css, /styles/dist/gui/core/footer.css, /styles/dist/gui/core/general/modal-window.css, /styles/dist/gui/core/general/metro-tiles.css, /styles/dist/gui/core/general/buttons.css, /styles/src/libs/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css, a resource was required but not found: /styles/src/libs/mCSB_buttons.png
    2016-01-01 20:57:46,005 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cz.test.dto.system.Client.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cz.test.dto.system.Client.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cz.test.dto.system.Client.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at cz.test.libs.core.privileges.PrivilegeApiService.generateAccessRules(PrivilegeApiService.groovy:45)
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:259)
        ... 8 more
    2016-01-01 20:57:46,012 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cz.test.dto.system.Client.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cz.test.dto.system.Client.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cz.test.dto.system.Client.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at cz.test.libs.core.privileges.PrivilegeApiService.generateAccessRules(PrivilegeApiService.groovy:45)
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:259)
        ... 8 more
```

DataSource.Groovy:

```
    dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}


// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource_system {
            dbCreate = "update"
            pooled = true
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
        }

        dataSource_usersettings {
            dbCreate = "update"
            pooled = true
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
        }
    }

    production {
        dataSource_system {
            dbCreate = "update"
            pooled = true
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
        }

        dataSource_usersettings {
            dbCreate = "update"
            pooled = true
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
        }
    }
}
```

Build.Config.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: might be a hibernate problem. AFAIK, hibernate is not tested with 12c yet. Can you post more details - your datasource.groovy?

Comment: edited first post, if need anything more, just tell.)

Comment: I can't see that you connect to an oracle - only h2... Which hibernate version are you using (buildconfig.groovy)?

Comment: grails-hibernate-2.2.4-sources.jar

Comment: I don't see that you've configured a connection to an oracle db in you datasource... Only h2. Is this correct?

Comment: edited first post, new DataSource.Groovy, did posted wrong one

Comment: You have a ':xe' postfix appended to your connection string. Have you checked what happens when you remove it. In Addition, it seems (from your stacktrace) that cz.test.dto.system.Client isn't recognized as domain class...

Comment: postfix helped to solve another problem with sid.

Answer (score 0):

anyway got this fixed by linking JAVA_HOME somehow export JAVA_HOME= didnt worked, so i used /tomcat/bin/patchclas.sh / env.sh and did some export JAVA_HOME=
and finaly got this working:)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling onto this question attempting to get an old grails application to run with Oracle 12c, something I've had to do is explicitly specify the dialect in the DataSource.groovy file:

```
dataSource_system {
            dbCreate = "update"
            pooled = true
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
            dialect = SequencePerTableOracleDialect
}
```